# Simplify table without package siunitx

Tags: tables, siunitx

I would like to simplify to generate the following table in a more simplified way, without using the `siunitx` package. The following table gives me a `\hbox` overfull and don’t know why:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!} {
\begin{tabular}{cc*{2}{S[table-format=-1.3]}
                       S[table-format= 1.3]
                       S
                       S[table-format=-1.3]
                       S[table-format= 3.3]
                       S[table-format= 1.3]}
\toprule
& {\stackon{}{$\mathbf{T^{x\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}} 
& {\stackon{[m]}{$\mathbf{T^{x\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}}
& {\stackon{[m]}{$\mathbf{T^y_{EO}}$}}
& {\stackon{[m]}{$\mathbf{T^{z\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}}
& {\stackon{[deg]}{$\mathbf{R^{x\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}}
& {\stackon{[deg]}{$\mathbf{R^y_{EO}}$}}
& {\stackon{[deg]}{$\mathbf{R^{z\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}}
& {\stackon{[px]}{\textbf{RMS}\vphantom{y}}} \\
    \midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{P\textit{n}P-LM}}
    & A & 2.748  & -0.135 & 2.175 & 119.232 & 1.368  & -76.261 & 0.240\\ 
    & B & 2.690  & 0.768  & 2.128 & 124.905 & -1.972 & -91.559 & 0.247\\
    & C & -1.576 & 1.139  & 2.146 & 120.264 & 1.428  & 98.205  & 0.255\\
    & D & -1.575 & -0.122 & 2.165 & 119.634 & -0.818 & 85.313  & 0.231\\
    \midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{EP\textit{n}P}}
    & A & 2.722  & -0.161 & 2.345 & 121.639 & 1.828  & -75.974 & 0.463\\
    & B & 2.649  & 0.729  & 2.259 & 127.082 & -0.881 & -91.444 & 0.432\\
    & C & -1.565 & 1.148  & 2.246 & 121.639 & 1.250  & 98.377  & 0.389\\
    & D & -1.547 & -0.077 & 2.238 & 120.951 & 0.199  & 85.428  & 0.372\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
\caption{Exterior orientation parameters and corresponding RMS error for all Kinect sensors defined within the chessboard coordinate system.}
\label{tab:rigidParams}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of `siunitx`? You've made an error: ``S[table-format= 3.3]`` should be `S[table-format= -2.3]`, `-76,261` is wider than say `666.666` because of the `-`

Comment: @daleif yes but then each column has a different width. How can I equally distribute the column width in my table?

Comment: Usually by making sure all columns use the same formatting. You are basically reserving space for each column. But I'd say it is not worth fiddling with

Comment: I'm curious, why don't you want to use `siunitx`? I think it's one of the most useful packages out there.

Answer (score 6):

The alignment here needs no significant work, so you could use `siunitx` with the '`dcolumn` strategy' or more simply just use `dcolumn`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}
  {
    @{}
    c
    c
    D{.}{.}{2.3}
    D{.}{.}{2.3}
    D{.}{.}{2.3}
    D{.}{.}{3.3}
    D{.}{.}{2.3}
    D{.}{.}{3.3}
    D{.}{.}{1.3}
    @{}
  }
\toprule
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\stackon{}{$\mathbf{T^{x\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\stackon{[m]}{$\mathbf{T^{x\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\stackon{[m]}{$\mathbf{T^y_{EO}}$}}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\stackon{[m]}{$\mathbf{T^{z\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\stackon{[deg]}{$\mathbf{R^{x\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\stackon{[deg]}{$\mathbf{R^y_{EO}}$}}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\stackon{[deg]}{$\mathbf{R^{z\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{\stackon{[px]}{\textbf{RMS}\vphantom{y}}} \\
  \midrule
    \multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{P\textit{n}P-LM}}
    & A & 2.748  & -0.135 & 2.175 & 119.232 & 1.368  & -76.261 & 0.240\\ 
    & B & 2.690  & 0.768  & 2.128 & 124.905 & -1.972 & -91.559 & 0.247\\
    & C & -1.576 & 1.139  & 2.146 & 120.264 & 1.428  & 98.205  & 0.255\\
    & D & -1.575 & -0.122 & 2.165 & 119.634 & -0.818 & 85.313  & 0.231\\
  \midrule
    \multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{EP\textit{n}P}}
    & A & 2.722  & -0.161 & 2.345 & 121.639 & 1.828  & -75.974 & 0.463\\
    & B & 2.649  & 0.729  & 2.259 & 127.082 & -0.881 & -91.444 & 0.432\\
    & C & -1.565 & 1.148  & 2.246 & 121.639 & 1.250  & 98.377  & 0.389\\
    & D & -1.547 & -0.077 & 2.238 & 120.951 & 0.199  & 85.428  & 0.372\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Personally I'd re-format the header and drop the `multirow` stuff but that's not in the question ...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did think of a package-free approach (or at least just using `array`), but it seemed a bit daft.

Answer (score 3):

Well, usually the `siuntx` is used for seting beautiful tables ... Since all number have the same number of decimals, you can replace `S` column type by `r`:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{showframe}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{cc*{7}{>{$}r<{$}}}
\toprule
& \stackon{}{$\mathbf{T^{x\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}
& \mc{\stackon{[m]}{$\mathbf{T^{x\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}}
& \mc{\stackon{[m]}{$\mathbf{T^y_{EO}}$}}
& \mc{\stackon{[m]}{$\mathbf{T^{z\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}}
& \mc{\stackon{[deg]}{$\mathbf{R^{x\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}}
& \mc{\stackon{[deg]}{$\mathbf{R^y_{EO}}$}}
& \mc{\stackon{[deg]}{$\mathbf{R^{z\vphantom{y}}_{EO}}$}}
& \mc{\stackon{[px]}{\textbf{RMS}\vphantom{y}}} \\
    \midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{P\textit{n}P-LM}}
    & A & 2.748  & -0.135 & 2.175 & 119.232 & 1.368  & -76.261 & 0.240\\
    & B & 2.690  & 0.768  & 2.128 & 124.905 & -1.972 & -91.559 & 0.247\\
    & C & -1.576 & 1.139  & 2.146 & 120.264 & 1.428  & 98.205  & 0.255\\
    & D & -1.575 & -0.122 & 2.165 & 119.634 & -0.818 & 85.313  & 0.231\\
    \midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{EP\textit{n}P}}
    & A & 2.722  & -0.161 & 2.345 & 121.639 & 1.828  & -75.974 & 0.463\\
    & B & 2.649  & 0.729  & 2.259 & 127.082 & -0.881 & -91.444 & 0.432\\
    & C & -1.565 & 1.148  & 2.246 & 121.639 & 1.250  & 98.377  & 0.389\\
    & D & -1.547 & -0.077 & 2.238 & 120.951 & 0.199  & 85.428  & 0.372\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Exterior orientation parameters and corresponding RMS error for all Kinect sensors defined within the chessboard coordinate system.}
    \label{tab:rigidParams}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Package `showframe` is added only to show page layout ...

\addendum:
To consider the comments below you need to put column header in `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}`. For simpler typing, I define new command `\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}` and accordingly change first row of table.

**Another "simple" solution:**

Add `makecell` package to preamble and instead of \stackon`macro from stack engine use`\thead{...}`. IN this case the code of preamble and row with column heads is:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{array,booktabs,makecell,multirow}
\usepackage{showframe}
\newcommand\vph{\vphantom{y}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \makegapedcells
    \setcellgapes{-2pt}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{cc*{7}{>{$}r<{$}}}
\toprule
& \thead[b]{$\mathbf{T^{x\vph}_{EO}}$}
& \thead[b]{\mathbf{T^{x\vph}_{EO}}\\ \mathrm{[m]}}
& \thead[b]{\mathbf{T^y_{EO}}\\ \mathrm{[m]}}
& \thead[b]{\mathbf{T^{z\vph}_{EO}}\\ \mathrm{[m]}}
& \thead[b]{\mathbf{R^{x\vph}_{EO}}\\ \mathrm{[deg]}}
& \thead[b]{\mathbf{R^y_{EO}}\\ \mathrm{[deg]}}
& \thead[b]{\mathbf{R^{z\vph}_{EO}}\\ \mathrm{[deg]}}
& \thead[b]{\textbf{RMS}\\ \mathrm{[px]}} \\
    \midrule
```

and obtained table:

[image]

Comment: @Zarko, dont you think that the headers should be centralized somehow?

Comment: I'm sure for this. However, you don't like to use `siunitx` which provide this .... See next answer with preposition of use  `dcolum` package ...

Comment: Now headers are centered ... on the two eays, as you can see from recent edit of my answer.